# Error: Socket closed with event 1002 in apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, graphql, apollo-client

im trying to make a subscription from apollo client to the server ,
In the server i use apollo-server-express.

The subscription works fine in the graphql playground but when I try to connect my client to the server I get this error.

Here is the part of code where i use useSubscription

1. Messsage.js (client)

```
const MESSAGE_CREATED_SUBSCRIPTION=gql`
subscription{
  messageCreated{
    content
    from
    to
  }
}
`

const {data:messageData,error:messageError}=useSubscription(MESSAGE_CREATED_SUBSCRIPTION)

useEffect(()=>{
console.log(messageError)
},[messageData,messageError])
```

2.index.js (client)

```
const authLink = setContext((req) => {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
  };
});
let httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
});

const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: "ws://localhost:4000/graphql",
    reconnect:true,
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    },
  })
);
httpLink=authLink.concat(httpLink)
const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

The error message I've been getting

```
Error: Socket closed with event 1002 
    at Object.error (index.ts:68:1)
    at client.mjs:411:1
```

3.The network tab
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the **same issue** when

- I was tried to use `@apollo/client` on the client-side.
- even though subscriptions worked perfectly with the `react-apollo` package
- even though subscriptions worked perfectly in the apollo studio

I was facing this **because** I used the old `subscriptions-transport-ws` on my gql server...

- the thing causing the issue was `WebSocketLink` setup
- note how we had to change

  - from `new GraphQLWsLink(createClient ...`
  - into `new GraphQLWsLink(SubscriptionClient...`
- details in [apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions#the-older-subscriptions-transport-ws-library) for this resolution...

relevant imports in case of `subscriptions-transport-ws` on the backend and wanting to use `@apollo/client` on the front-end:

```
import { WebSocketLink } from "@apollo/client/link/ws";
import { SubscriptionClient } from "subscriptions-transport-ws";

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(
  new SubscriptionClient("ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions", {
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: user.authToken
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Hey thanks! i figured it out.